# css text-align bug

Tags: css, typography

I'm seeing a strange text-align bug using FF 3.0.11 on Ubuntu-Hardy.

[test case](http://bbby.org/share/css_bug1.html)

The letter "f" is way out in left field. I can also make this happen with a variety of fonts and sizes, involving as many as three letters flying away and stacking onto each other.

Is this known? Is a fix known?

(I have another question open about this that I'm closing asap, as the context has been ruled out)

Comment: I use Firefox 3.0.11 in Intrepid Ibex and don't see any strange align. Can you post an screenshot?

Comment: http://bbby.org/share/css_bug2.html passes w3c markup validation. same bug :(

Comment: screenshot = http://bbby.org/share/css_bug1.png

Comment: Take note, bug occurs only if font-size is between 250px and 270px.  Everything above and below that displays correctly.

Comment: Also, bug does not occur if font-family is anything other than Arial or if text-align is not center.

Comment: Verdana has seen it's own range. The range seems to be per letter, and affected by the line-height. That is, different line-height, different range bug is noticed.

Comment: @scvalex: font-family: Helvetica seems to reproduce the bug. Though Calibri, Cambria, Consolas, Times New Roman...and many others, don't.

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking this question of the firefox developers.

Answer (score 1):

Does anything change if you add a "text-align:center;" to the Div css?

Comment: negative.  The one I keep changing is http://bbby.org/share/css_bug_dev.html , but please note that it's changing as ideas come in.

Comment: Maybe if the line height is smaller than the height of the actual font it doesn't work?

Comment: lineHeight is never small than the fontSize. I assume that they use the same measure. fontSize is generally 70-75% that of the lineHeight in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same bug (FF3.0.11/Ubuntu 8.04):

[image]

The weirdness is that If I select the centred text I get:

[image]

This seems to merit investigation... O.o